# How do I get passengers on my roller coasters?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-classic

I am playing RTC Classic on my phone, a Samsung V20. I had the Timber Terror break down with a crash and then rebuilt it. The same thing happened with the Lumberjack, but when I rebuilt it, nobody came back to ride either roller coaster. I then scrapped Timber Terror altogether and built a Flight of the Phoenix, but even with a free ride marketing campaign, I can't get even one passenger on the roller coaster because they can't seem to cross from my built footbridge to the one that was built into the ride, even though they match up perfectly. I've tried clearing my footbridge and rebuilding it, but nothing is working.

This is my favorite game EVER and I've been looking for it for a very long time, so if you have hints I am ready to try anything to keep playing! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Crashes have a major impact on both the ride, and the overall Park, for a few (in-game) months, and even with free entry, or free rides, no one will be willing to ride the affected attraction.

[Source](http://rct.wikia.com/wiki/Crash#Delayed_Effects)

The best bet is to completely remove the entire ride, and replace it - this can be with the exact same ride, but again, your Park will not have many guests that are willing to ride the attractions in the coming months.

As for the issue with the boardwalk, it depends on how long it is. From memory, I believe guests will turn around within 1 "block" of the attraction's queue entrance. if your boardwalk is only that long, that might be the cause. The other thing to try, is pick up a guest, and place them on that square, and see what they do. You can also click on guests to see what they are thinking - some may have thoughts about that attraction in question.